# How to save a custom upload field in the public disk

Tags: laravel-backpack, laravel-10

I have created my custom upload field and when I try to upload a file it's not saving in the public folder, instead it's saved from the C:\xampp\tmp\ directory. I want to know on how to save it in the public folder

I tried using the withFiles, but it's giving me errors because of the type I used for the custom field.

```
        CRUD::field('file_path')
            ->label('Upload Files')
            ->type('custom_upload_field')
            ->withFiles([
                'disk' => 'public',
                'path' => 'uploads'
            ]);
```

If I use the code above, it will have conflict with the type because I'm using a custom field with that file name

Here's the blade file for the custom field:

```
{{-- custom_upload_field field --}}
@php
    $field['value'] = old_empty_or_null($field['name'], '') ?? ($field['value'] ?? ($field['default'] ?? ''));
@endphp

@include('crud::fields.inc.wrapper_start')
    <label>{!! $field['label'] !!}</label>
    @include('crud::fields.inc.translatable_icon')

    <input type="file"
        name="{{ $field['name'] }}"
        data-init-function="bpFieldInitDummyFieldElement"
        value="{{ $field['value'] }}"
        @include('crud::fields.inc.attributes')>
    
    {{-- HINT --}}
    @if (isset($field['hint']))
        <p class="help-block">{!! $field['hint'] !!}</p>
    @endif
    @include('crud::fields.inc.wrapper_end')

    {{-- CUSTOM CSS --}}
    @push('crud_fields_styles')
    {{-- How to load a CSS file? --}}
    @basset('custom_upload_fieldFieldStyle.css')

    {{-- How to add some CSS? --}}
    @bassetBlock('backpack/crud/fields/custom_upload_field_field-style.css')
        <style>
            .custom_upload_field_field_class {
            display: none;
                
            }
        </style>
    @endBassetBlock
    @endpush

    {{-- CUSTOM JS --}}
    @push('crud_fields_scripts')
    {{-- How to load a JS file? --}}
    @basset('custom_upload_fieldFieldScript.js')
            


    {{-- How to add some JS to the field? --}}
    @bassetBlock('path/to/script.js')
    <script>
        function bpFieldInitDummyFieldElement(element) {
            // this function will be called on pageload, because it's
            // present as data-init-function in the HTML above; the
            // element parameter here will be the jQuery wrapped
            // element where init function was defined
            console.log(element.val());
        }
    </script>
    @endBassetBlock

    
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar to come up with an answer and it wasn't successful.

I have created an issue on the repo and assigned my colleague to fix it.

Let's continue the discussion there. https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/5394

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope we can fix this issue. I've been looking for an answer for a week now

Comment: Hey eps, thanks for the question. I've just added a section to the docs explaining how to add the uploaders in the custom fields: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-uploaders#configuring-uploaders-in-custom-fields